# error in Implement page curl on android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, page-curl

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/

with reference of this URL, I Developed page curl effect in my Android application. I want effect like book page curl. when the page curl its back side page shows in mirror effect. but after page flip page display properly. I don't know what's the problem?

Comment: I think that's not the error. That's the implemented functionality with that pagecurl example

Comment: @SpK Agreed, its not a problem

Comment: ok but i want effect like book page, so what can i do now ?

Comment: You've to customize that code with your needs?

Comment: ok i try it from last 4 days.but i don't no how that page is inverted (or from witch part of code).